Flask App Builder: is it possible to remove firstname, lastname, username from the User entity?
I want to make the registration process easy as possible, by removing unesseccary information.
I can add my own attributes like phone_number by creating a new class and inheriting from User, but the problem is:



I dont need firstname, lastname and username... How can I change the User entity ?



I saw that these variables are used all over the codebase (for example in the login route, registration route, regsistrationUserModel, ...)
I thought of using a custom form and add_post(self, item) to overwrite the firstname, lastname, username, with the provided user email before persiting to the datasbase ... but is there a better (cleaner) way ?
